# Swift backend with perfct framwork

Tags: swift, swift3, server-side-swift

Hi i am learning Swift perfect backend i am stuck how to add mongodb dependencies in my project, If someone know how to do please help me

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftBackend",
    products: [
        .library(name: "PerfectMongoDB", targets: ["PerfectMongoDB"])
    ],

    dependencies: [
        // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
        .package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git", from: "3.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectSideRepos/Perfect-CMongo.git", from: "0.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectSideRepos/Perfect-CBSON.git", from: "0.0.0"),
        .package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectLib.git", from: "3.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "SwiftBackend",
            dependencies: ["PerfectHTTPServer" , "PerfectLib" , "PerfectMongoDB"]),
        ]
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please follow this instruction to add dependencies to your Swift project:

1. create a blank folder with your project name.
2. Inside this folder, use `swift package init --type=executable` to initialize the Package.swift automatically:

In your case, it looks like this:

```
$ mkdir SwiftBackend && cd SwiftBackend && swift package init --type=executable
```

3. modify the dependencies. Should be like this:

   // swift-tools-version:4.0
   import PackageDescription

   let package = Package(
       name: "SwiftBackend",
       dependencies: [
           .package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git", from: "3.0.0"),
           .package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-MongoDB.git", from: "3.0.0"),
       ],
       targets: [
           .target(
               name: "SwiftBackend",
               dependencies: ["PerfectHTTPServer", "PerfectMongoDB"]),
       ]
   )

there may be some warnings but should work without any issues.

Comment: Hey PerfectlyRock i want ask more question plz ping me if u will be free to ans me... swiftdeveloper11@gmail.com i want  to know about deployment of perfect server.

Answer (score 0):

i found the ans its `import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "SwiftBackend",

```
products: [
    .library(name: "PerfectMongoDB", targets: ["SwiftBackend"])
],

dependencies: [
    // Dependencies declare other packages that this package depends on.
    .package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git", from: "3.0.0"),
    .package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-MongoDB.git", from: "0.0.0"),
    .package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/PerfectLib.git", from: "3.0.0")
],
targets: [
    .target(
        name: "SwiftBackend",
      dependencies: ["PerfectHTTPServer" , "PerfectLib" , "MongoDB"]),
    ]
```

)`

Comment: Wrong tag Perfect-MongoDB "0.0.0" should be at least "3.0.0"
Don't include PerfectLib explicitly, Perfect-HTTPServer has already had it.

Comment: hey  PerfectlyRock i need ur help , i am trying to deploy my backend with herkou but stuck in some point not able to recognise what isthe issue :-Build failure: Sorry, only Ubuntu 14.04 is currently supported,

Comment: I haven't seen users of Perfect+Heroku for two years while Perfect has many many  updates; anyway Perfect 3 only support Ubuntu 16.04. You can goto http://perfect.ly to get instant support, anyway.